# How to do an IN with a subquery returning 2 columns?

Tags: sql

I have this Query

```
SELECT *
FROM GUITARS.FENDER
WHERE FENDER.GUITARTYPE IN (
SELECT GUITARTYPE,GUITARSUBTYPE
FROM GUITARS.GUITAR_TYPE
WHERE GuitarColor = 'RED')
```

I can get it to run when I'm only doing GUITARTYPE in the subquery but not both GUITARTYPE,GUITARSUBTYPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `in`, use `exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM GUITARS.FENDER
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM GUITARS.GUITAR_TYPE
              WHERE GuitarColor = 'RED' AND
                    FENDER.GUITARTYPE = GUITARTYPE.GUITARTYPE AND
                    FENDER.GUITARSUBTYPE = GUITARTYPE.GUITARSUBTYPE
             );
```